# Python: Executing multiple functions in parallel

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I wanted to clarify something because I'm not sure if my idea of understanding running in parallel is correct. Below is my code, but running it will return 1 to 8 first and then 10 to 19. I wanted to see it return `1,10,2,11,3,13,etc`. because that's what I believe should happen if the 2 functions are running next to each other at the same time. Is this actually happening but just printing out in order because it's processing it so quickly?

```
def func1():
    for i in range(1,9):
      print(i)

def func2():
    for i in range(10,20):
      print(i)

from multiprocessing import Process

p1 = Process(target=func1)
p1.start()
p2 = Process(target=func2)
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works but the function ends too fast, try this instead so you can see them working in parallel:

```
import time
def func1():
    for i in range(1, 9):
        time.sleep(2)
        print(i)


def func2():
    for i in range(10, 20):
        time.sleep(3)
        print(i)


from multiprocessing import Process

p1 = Process(target=func1)
p1.start()
p2 = Process(target=func2)
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

Comment: awesome thanks! the sleep makes it shows what im looking for pretty much. this clearified things

Answer (score -1):

It runs too fast, while compiler going to execute p2, p1 is already over. And by the way python parallelism is a sudo-paralelism, there is no multi-threading on python.

Comment: `a sudo-paralelism, there is no multi-threading on python` Where did you get that? That is just plain wrong. He is even using multiple processes and not threading.

Comment: From the documentation: "The multiprocessing package offers both local and remote concurrency, effectively side-stepping the Global Interpreter Lock by using subprocesses instead of threads. Due to this, the multiprocessing module allows the programmer to fully leverage multiple processors on a given machine."  ...Nothing pseudo about that.

Comment: It seems that I am wrong about this parallelism, sorry about that.